# find out a specific url in child window adressbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a way to detect that child window has opened a specific URL ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openWin()
  {
    var child=window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=bing");
    var timer = setInterval(checkChild, 100);
    function checkChild() {
        var urll = child.location;
        if (urll.match(/bing.com.*/)) {
         alert("bing opened")
        }
        if (child.closed) {
            alert("Child window closed");   
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />
</body>
</html>
```

User opens `https://www.google.com/search?q=bing` in child window and click on search result and go to bing.com.
How can i find out that child window's URL is LIKE to bing.com ?
is it possible generally to do that? or i'm wasting my time?
if it is imposible , is there any other way?

Comment: impossible when it is a different domain

Comment: is there any other way? @epascarello

Comment: Same Origin Policy prevents it.

Comment: is there an alternative? @epascarello

Comment: Build your own browser?